Data structure for tracking boolean clauses size
Given an unordered sequence of n boolean conjonction clauses which may contain duplicates, I am looking for a data structure that would track the number of clauses grouped by the number of variables in them.
This list can be quite large so the internal representation in this data structure as an explicit list won't be efficient.
I would like to provide 3 operations to that structure:

a query operation to retrieve the number of clauses by their size
a concatenation operation that would append 2 lists together (ex: the concatenation of an instance of 2 clauses of 3 variables and another
one of 1 clause of 3 variables would generate an instance of 3
clauses of 3 variables)
an intersection that would take in input a boolean clause and would apply a boolean AND on each clause of the list and adjust the counters accordingly. (ex: I have one clause v1 and v2 and v3 so one clause of 3 variables, if I do intersection with clause not v2 then the result is there is no clause. If I do intersection with clause v1 then the result is one clause of 3 variables. If I do intersection with v4 then the result is one clause of 4 variables.)

This data structure can be initialized with a boolean clause then intersection and union operations can be used to combine them.
I have tried by myself but I am not able to find algorithms with complexity lower than exponential time to solve this for intersection operation.

Thank you for your feedback! The list is provided explicity as an input but it is not translated as an internal representation in the data structure. Practically, I would generate a data structure for each conjonction then combine them with union operation to generate the "view" of the list that would provide me with the counters I need. I don't need to regenerate the original list so information can be lost, the only important thing would be to keep the counters exact. I have updated my question, please let me know if I can provide more details!

Thank you for the edits!  If a clause appears twice, do you count it twice or once?  Does concatenation mean concatenation or union?  Concatenation can create duplicates, union can't.  What is the best implementation of this data structure you've got and the running time of each operation for this implementation?  I don't understand why even the most naive approach would take exponential time.

Thanks again for your contribution! It is indeed a concatenation operation! In the best implementation I have got, I am representing for each variable and its negation the operations that an intersection would apply on the counters. As working with counters play well with additivity, it is then easy to compute concatenation. The query operation runs in constant time, concatenation is linear with the number of operations tracked, and my unfinished prototype for intersection would run in exponential time if I compose concatenation and intersections in nested loops.
